# Insert or Update in one statement for access db

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to wirte an sql statement such that I can either update (if record already exists) or insert a data record into an access db via an OleDBCommand.

sql statement:

```
string sql = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblMitarbeiter_Arbeitsform WHERE (fkLogin = '" + _Login.ToUpper() + "') AND (fkIdArbeitsform = " + dr.fkIdArbeitsform  + "))";
       sql += " UPDATE tblMitarbeiter_Arbeitsform SET (Prozent = " + dr.Prozent + ")";
       sql += " WHERE (fkLogin = '" + _Login.ToUpper() + "') AND (fkIdArbeitsform = " + dr.fkIdArbeitsform + ")";
       sql += " ELSE INSERT INTO tblMitarbeiter_Arbeitsform (fkLogin, fkIdArbeitsform, Prozent) VALUES ('" + _Login.ToUpper() + "', " + dr.fkIdArbeitsform + ", " + dr.Prozent + ")";


oCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, getOekobonusConnection());
oCmd.ExecuteScalar();
//oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

both ExecuteScalar and ExecuteNonQuery are not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "are not working"  - more specifically?

Comment: if you use ExecuteNonQuery to execute it, what error message do you see? as Mitch said, you should provide more info to reproduce.

Comment: Does it work if you take the generated SQL and run it directly in Access?

Comment: MS Access uses a file-based database and cannot execute more than one SQL statement at a time.

Answer (score 4):

There's no control of flow constructs in Access SQL so you can't do an IF. You would have to split the logic and do the test in your code, then issue an update or insert accordingly.